# Creating an Arabic book with a commentary and footnote

Tags: arabic, kile, arabtex

I wanted to write an arabic book that includes a commentary and footnote, in the style that  most arabic books are written in. currently im playing around with arabtex, and trying myself.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice as to how i would achieve this. Im pretty sure someone mustve made a template or package somewhere; im just having trouble finding it.

Attached is a picture of a typical book that is written in the style i want to copy. The page is split into three sections: the section at the top is the text itself, underneath is the commentary, and at the bottom is the footnote. [image]
The dotted line on the top section is to show that the sentence continues to the next page. in the second section the red part in brackets is the original text, and the part in the fancy brackets and different font is Quran.

I want to copy the entire style of these books, including the fonts (which i believe is either amiri or scheherazade, and including amiri-quran for the quran quotes), the lines, page numbers and chapter names in arabic etc.

If you need anymore info i can provide.

Thanks

sys info: using kile on kubuntu 18.04, installed arabtex.

Comment: The font is most likely Lotus Arabic. Isn't ArabTeX old? Did you look at XeLaTeX? `reledmac` is a package that might help.

Comment: Arabtex is pretty old, i also came across arabic-book, which ive tried to get working. Ill give reledmac a try. lotus arabic seems correct, Jazakallah Khair

Comment: Wa Iyyak. Also look at the `ekdosis` package. It might have something that suits your needs.